Compare two columns in different dataframes and filter each for common values with pandas
I have two dataframes, both with a country column. There are some countries that are not common to both datasets. I want to filter out these unique countries so that each dataframe now only contains countries that also exist in the other.
For instance, if Algeria is in dataframe A but not in dataframe B, I want the Algeria row removed from dataframe A. (And likewise for countries in B but not A)
I tried using isin, I need to remove the False rows - am I on the right track?:
x.Country.isin(y.Country)

83      True
111     True
0       True
4       True
67      True
       ...  
175    False
174    False
130    False
49      True
50      True
Name: Country, Length: 176, dtype: bool


Try using np.intersect1d:
np.intersect1d(x['Country'], y['Country'])

If you want to preserve the order:
x['Country'] = x.loc[x['Country'].isin(y['Country']), 'Country']
y['Country'] = y.loc[y['Country'].isin(x['Country']), 'Country']


You are quite close, to remove the False's you can pass these boolean into .loc across each of the entire DataFrames.
import pandas as pd


x = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['USA', 'MEX', 'BRA', 'CAN'],
    'value':   [1,     2,     3    , 4    ],
})
y = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['CAN', 'MEX', 'ARG'],
    'value':   [5,      6,     7   ],
})

filt_x = x.loc[x['country'].isin(y['country'])]
filt_y = y.loc[y['country'].isin(x['country'])]

print(
    filt_x,
    #   country  value
    # 1     MEX      2
    # 3     CAN      4

    filt_y,
    #   country  value
    # 0     CAN      5
    # 1     MEX      6
    sep='\n\n',
)


why not simply :
x_filtered = x[x['Country'].isin(y['Country'])]
y_filtered = y[y['Country'].isin(x['Country'])]

